# How to undo git stash save --keep-index

Tags: git, git-stash

I was working on deleting flutter from my MacOs and used the command git stash save --keep-index, which deleted every single thing on my Mac. I had really important documents on my laptop and really need those files back.
Would really appreciate the help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `git stash pop`

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: `git reset --hard && git stash pop`.  Read the rest first though!

A regular `git stash save` or `git stash push` works by:

- making two commits,<sup>1</sup> on *no* branch;<sup>2</sup>
- running `git reset --hard`.

A `git stash save` run with `--keep-index` modifies this second step: instead of `git reset --hard`, Git checks out the *index* commit made in the first step.

The idea behind this practice is simple enough.  We start with the fact that Git makes *new* commits not from what is in your *working tree*, but rather from what is in Git's index.  Then, on top of this fact, we add the idea that there are test programs (compilers, linters, style-checkers, and so on) that read a directory-full of files, such as your working tree files, to tell you whether these files are Good™ or Bad.™

For these various testing programs to do their job, then, we need to take the *proposed commit*—which is normally in *Git's index*, not in your working tree—and put it somewhere.  Then we can run the testing program.  If it thinks your proposed commit is good, you can make that commit.  If it finds fault(s) with your proposed commit, you can fix them up and try again.

So: where should `git stash` put this proposed commit?  That is, we need a tree, like your working tree, full of the files that are in Git's index.  The answer that someone came up with is: *Let's put this in your working tree.*  **But that means that Git must destroy the contents of your working tree!**  But—hang on—`git stash` just *saved* the contents of your working tree, in one of those two commits-on-no-branch it just made!  So it must be OK to *destroy* it now, because it's saved!  The `stash` command can kill off all *those* files and replace them with the ones from the *index* commit.

This is what `--keep-index` does.  That's the whole *point* of `--keep-index`: since `git stash` is already making two (or three, per footnote 1) commits, that creates enough room to *wipe out* all your files, and put in their place the files from the index commit made in the "make some commits on no branch" step.  Now you can *test* these files, and if they're good, make a commit from them.

There's one big problem<sup>3</sup> (and numerous smaller problems) with this approach, but it does actually work: you run, e.g., `git stash --keep-index` or `git stash -a --keep-index`, then run the linter or whatever program(s) you want, then run `git reset --hard`, then run `git stash pop` to apply-and-drop the stash and put everything—your working tree *and* Git's index—back the way they all were before you ran `git stash` at all.  The linter's errors, if there were any, are still there on your screen, and now you can fix them.  If there were no errors, now you can run `git commit`.

This does, however, leave `git stash --keep-index` as a sort of trap for the unwary, because `git stash pop` will try to apply the saved work-tree atop the saved-and-then-put-into-your-working-tree index.  If you had a "clean" index—if `git status`, before the `git stash` command, would have said that there were no changes "staged for commit", but some changes "not staged for commit"—everything is OK and a simple `git stash pop` suffices.  Otherwise, though, you need that `git reset --hard` first ... and you must be aware that this will destroy any work you did *since* the `git stash save --keep-index`.

---

<sup>1</sup>These two commits hold the contents of Git's index, and of your working tree, respectively.  If you add the `-u` or `-a` options (their long spellings, `--include-untracked` / `--all`, do exactly the same thing here), `git stash` adds a *third* commit containing extra files, and adds a third step of removing from your working tree each of the file stored in that third commit.

<sup>2</sup>Remember that any commit can be on zero, one, two, ten, or even millions of branches (if you have that many).  By making sure that these two commits are on *no* branches at all, `git stash` tries to make it easier for you to "think of" those commits as being available from *all* branches.  I don't think this is a particularly good idea, since all commits are *always* available at all times, but that's how `git stash` works.

<sup>3</sup>The big problem is that `git stash --keep-index` *does nothing at all* if your working tree and index match the current commit.  This makes automating the process impossible (or at least too difficult so that people keep getting it wrong): people write pre-commit hooks that use `git stash --keep-index` before doing the linting, then do a `git reset --hard && git stash pop`, and if the `git stash --keep-index` did nothing, this pops *some other stash*, with horrible side effects.